# How to test application

Tags: c++

I am trying to test my static library that i used to build in win xp 32bit. So, I made a test application that utilizes the static lib to print out a code.

Now, i wanted to see its behavior on a 64 bit OS. How do i go about doing that?
Do i need to install vs2008 on that one and create my test application on it then port my static lib and build it there? Or is there a way where i can just port my existing application exe and static lib to a 64 bit machine?

Also is it true that on a 64 bit OS i need to have a 32bit app in order to run a static lib that was created in a 32bit environment?

The goal is to check to see if my static lib would work in a 64bit environment. Also, please note they will be installing this static lib on multiple computers so I do not expect any network access per se.

The one API that i am giving to them uses `const char *` as an input parameter since I use strings internally. Not sure if I need to create an optional parameter of `__int64` and then convert that to a string internally as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using VisualStudio, you can build 64-bit binaries on a 32-bit box.  You just can't run them there.  Whether it is a good idea to use a 32-bit machine as your build machine is a whole other story, but yes, it can be done.

So you build your 64-bit app on OLDCLUNKER32, which is a 32 bit box.  Move those binaries over to NEWHOTNESS64 which is a 64 bit box, install any Visual Studio redistributable packages you might need, and run your app.  You can run 32-bit code on a 64-bit box, but you can't mix 64-bit and 32-bit binaries in a single application.  For example, your EXE and all DLLs must be the same, weither 64 or 32 bit.

Your clients don't need to install VisualStudio to run your app, right?  Well, neither do you.  Install the appropriate redistributable for your platform, and you should be able to run your app.

Comment: how do i deploy my test app which uses my static lib without installing vs2008? i think I just don't know how to do that...

Comment: Your end-users would need to install (or already have installed) a "redist" package for VisualStudio.  You can get this from the MS download website, and you need to make sure your end user installs the correct one.  Each combination of target platform, compiler release, and compiler service pack level requires a different redist package.  For example, this redist is for 32-bit apps compiled using MSVC 2008 SP1: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Write good unit tests, build them on 64-bit platform and execute. If some unit tests fail, you have a problem.

Comment: Unit tests are not the end-all, be-all.  There is no substitute for running your app on a target platform.

Comment: @John Dibling You are right - they are not. I look at unit tests as bigger safe net. I found somewhere that unit tests are catching 30% of all problems, and my experience tells me it is more. BTW I am doing TDD, where the unit tests are dictating the design.

Comment: other than installing vs2008 on target box and porting my static lib. is there way to just use my app that i made on a 32bit env? like say copy the exe and lib and see if it works? just curious how that would work?

Comment: @user245823 How did you plan to do it? If you do not have 64-bit system where you can build and execute, you have to build your unit test using cross-compiler. When you build the unit test, copy it to the target and execute.